# TextView Compound Drawable MvvmCross Binding

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

`TextView` has some `DrawableXXX` properties like `DrawableStart`, `DrawableEnd`, `DrawableTop`, etc. to show a `Drawable` next to the `TextView` text. Is it possible to bind this property using MvvmCross? I've tried using `local:MvxBind="Drawablename 'check'"` in my binding but it fails showing an MvxBind error:

> Failed to create target binding for binding DrawableName for check

If this binding is not implemented in MvvmCross then how would I go about doing this on my own? Is the method used by [N+28](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-28-CustomBinding) still the recommended way to add a custom binding?

Comment: The method used by N+28 for custom binding is still valid for MvvmCross 4.x. If you're using MvvmCross 5.x then there is a typed `MvxAndroidTargetBinding` you can use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently any MvvmCross define target binding for adding compound drawables. However, you can easily add your own. If you are using MvvmCross 5+ you can take advantage of the new typed custom binding classes. ***Note***, the example below has set the drawable to be placed on the left, however, you can choose to place at any direction (or multiple).

```
public class CompoundDrawablesDrawableNameBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding<TextView, string>
{
    public const string BindingIdentifier = "CompoundDrawableName";

    public CompoundDrawablesDrawableNameBinding(TextView target) : base(target)
    {
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

    protected override void SetValueImpl(TextView target, string value)
    {
        var resources = AndroidGlobals.ApplicationContext.Resources;
        var id = resources.GetIdentifier(value, "drawable", AndroidGlobals.ApplicationContext.PackageName);
        if (id == 0)
        {
            MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Warning,
                "Value '{0}' was not a known compound drawable name", value);
            return;
        }

        target.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            left: id,
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0);
    }
}
```

Then register in your `Setup.cs`

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<TextView>(
        CompoundDrawablesDrawableNameBinding.BindingIdentifier,
        textView => new CompoundDrawablesDrawableNameBinding(textView));
}
```

Then in your XML you can use

`local:MvxBind="CompoundDrawableName <<YOUR PROPERTY TO BIND TO>>"`

Comment: If you are support API 17+ you can also you the `SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds` which caters for `start`, `top`,  `end` and `bottom`.

Comment: could you make a PR to add this?

Comment: @Martijn00, I'm not sure how to generalise this for Mvx binding in order to allow the developer the option to select one or more images per direction. Essentially, we would need a way to take in 1 - 4  different images and apply them to 4 different possible directions. I create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2629) to continue this conversion.